# Does empty string match mongo db schema of required?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a mongodb schema like below.

```
const DemoSchema: Schema = new Schema({
  demoProperty1: { type: String, required: true }
});
```

I create a document with syntax in node js server like below.

```
const savedDemo = await this.demoModel.create({demoProperty1:""});
```

Why it is returning error message

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ValidationError:
```

How to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/schematype.html#schematype_SchemaType-checkRequired):

```
// Use this to allow empty strings to pass the `required` validator
mongoose.Schema.Types.String.checkRequired(v => typeof v === 'string');
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes I have fix this issue by trial and error.
Empty string is not eligible for mongodb required schema,
Took me 5 hours to figure it out. I can just passed in any string but not an empty string to make it valid and passed without any error.